# How do I terminate the old connection when a user of the same account login again?

Tags: permissions, sql-server-2019, service-accounts

I want to set up a server while multiple users could login at the same time, as long as they are not the "same user".

How could I set it up so when the user with the account username "Bob" login again, whether it's from the same computer or another, the old connection will be terminated?

Thanks for your help.

Much appreciated!

**Edit:**

"Bob" is a Database user account, the "User ID" in the "Connection String", I'm sorry I don't really know what it is called.

Comment: Hi! How would you identify Bob apart from the other logins? How would SQL Server then have to identify Bob?

Comment: @RandiVertongen I'm sorry! I've edited my question, basically "Bob" is the account username, if he login with "Bob" again, the old Bob will be kicked out.

Comment: Is "Bob" a SQL Login using SQL Server Authentication or Windows Authentication?...or you want to handle both cases?

Comment: But... why? This seems more like [a prank](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2018/02/throttle-logins-sql-server/) than a practical administrative choice. If you're seeing ad-hoc users hammering a shared server, could you consider offloading their traffic to a reporting instance? Or [gating them into a resource group](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/resource-governor/resource-governor) if they *absolutely must* be connected to production?

Comment: I apologize for my pool English, please see the updated edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want to use a [Logon Trigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/triggers/logon-triggers?view=sql-server-ver15) to manage this. This specific part of the docs linked above mentions how you can limit the number of sessions for a specific Login:

> You can use logon triggers to audit and control server sessions, such
> as by tracking login activity, restricting logins to SQL Server, or
> limiting the number of sessions for a specific login.

The first example in the docs is close to what you want, except it'll rollback the newer logins. If you want to kill the older logins you can use the `login_time` column of `sys.dm_exec_sessions` and `kill` the older sessions for that specific `login_name`.